# Is it out of memory for MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, memory-management, cplex

I met a problem when I run my code, every time I run a relatively larger instance, then the program got stuck and matlab then is not responding, I need to restart the computer, basically I will need to use cplexqcp function to solve SOCP in ILOG CPLEX. I debug the code and following is where the program got stuck

```
    for i=1:prog.Sddcount
        if prog.Sdd(i).totalSddVars~=0
            for j=1:prog.Sdd(i).totalSdd   
                diagvec = sparse([varSum+prog.Sdd(i).numAlpha+(j-1)*5+4:varSum+prog.Sdd(i).numAlpha+(j-1)*5+6],[1 1 1],[1 -1 1],prog.Socp.numVars+1,1);

                prog.Socp.qc(alphaSum+j).a=sparse([],[],[],prog.Socp.numVars+1,1);
                prog.Socp.qc(alphaSum+j).rhs=0;              
                prog.Socp.qc(alphaSum+j).Q = spdiags(diagvec(:),0,prog.Socp.numVars+1,prog.Socp.numVars+1);     
            end
            alphaSum = alphaSum + prog.Sdd(i).totalSdd;
        end
        varSum = varSum + prog.Sdd(i).totalVars;
    end
```

And the parameter of one instance that kills the program is

```
prog.Sddcount=11;
[prog.Sdd.totalSdd]=[1540  1540  1540  1540  1540  1540  1540  1540  1540  1540 7875] 
prog.Socp.numVars=117061;
```

I guess it might be the huge size (117061 by 117061) and large number(sum([prog.Sdd.totalSdd])) of matrix Q , but it is highly sparse and only three entries is nonzero, so I think it would be OK...but every time I run an instance of similar size, it crashes. From the information above, can anyone tell where the problem is? Is it out of memory or I need to allocate enough memory in advance for

```
prog.Socp.qc.Q
```

And how can I modify the code?
Thanks very much.

Comment: It may take a time to go through the code, but if you have a 117061x116061 matrix, which is not sparse (and I refer to elements different from 0 rather than of type sparse), you will definitely have memory problems. Have to tried to use the debugger and check the memory consumed for every breakpoint?

Comment: Is it possible for you to recreate this behavior with an executable code? My initial guess would be that there is a conversion to full somewhere in there, but I can't spot it right away.

Comment: You can also simply have the task manager open and see if the memory fills up when running the code.

Comment: @patrik could you please tell me how to check the memory consumed for every breakpoint? use a command or a tool? thanks

Comment: `whos`? Task manager? The profiler? This does really not need a breakpoint, but as you say your computer freezes, you may want to set a few breakpoints to be able to check before your computer freezes.

Comment: I checked the task manager...the physical memory rapidly goes to 98% ... I need to think about how to modify the code... thanks guys.

Comment: I have run into this problem from time to time. After you run out of physical ram, it starts using swap space on the hard drive, which slows the program WAY down and essentially freezes the computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have already helped OP find that his program was using all the computers physical memory and essentially freezing the computer. One way to check for this would be to include the following code;

```
max_memory_bytes = 2^32; %limit my script to 4Gb

for i = doing stuff
stuff stuff stuff

mem = memory;
if mem.MemUsedMATLAB > max_memory_bytes
    error('Matlab exceeded memory limit of %d Bytes',max_memory_bytes);
end
```

Memory is a builtin function that provides some useful information. By calling it periodically, one can automatically monitor memory usage and error out before your computer freezes. Of course, if inside the loop you call something like `ones(1e4)` that uses a ton of memory, this addition won't help you very much.